# Python libxml2: querying xml using xpath

Tags: python, xml, text, xpath, libxml2

I am trying to read an XML file from a command line argument. I am new to using libxml2 and XPath in general. I want to query using XPath.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                                                     
<xmi:XMI xmlns:cas="http:///text/cas.ecore" xmlns:audioform="http:something" xmlns:xmi="http://blahblah" xmlns:lib="http://blahblah" xmlns:solr="http:blahblah" xmlns:tcas="http:///blah" xmi:version="2.0">                                                
  <cas:NULL xmi:id="0"/>                                                                                                                                     
  <cas:Sofa xmi:id="9" Num="1" ID="First" Type="text" String="play a song"/>    
  <cas:Sofa xmi:id="63" Num="2" ID="Second" Type="text" String="Find a contact"/>     
  <cas:Sofa xmi:id="72" Num="3" ID="Third" Type="text" String="Send a message"/>     
  <lib:Confidence xmi:id="1" sofa="9" begin="0" end="1" key="context" value="" confidence="1.0"/>                                                                          
</xmi:XMI>
```

**Code:**

```
def main(argv):
  try:
     xmlfile=argv[0]
     doc=libxml2.parseFile(xmlfile)
     root2=doc.children

     print root2  # This prints everything but <?xml version="1.0"?> 
     result= root2.xpathEval("//*")

     for node in result:
       print node
       print node.nodePath(), node.name, node.content
```

I want to go further and do some kind of processing using this file.

1. How do I get values like 63 using xpath ?  from `xmi:id="63"`.
2. Find String where `xmi:id = "72"`.  Result should be *"Send a message"*
3. Find string where `xmi:id = 72 and ID= "Third"`.  Result should be *"Send a message"*
4. I tried using `node.Path()`, `node.name` and `node.content` for this node:

   ```
   <cas:Sofa xmi:id="9" Num="1" ID="First" Type="text" String="play a song"/>
   ```

   The results are: `/xmi:XMI/cas:Sofa[1]` as `nodePath()`, *Sofa* as name and prints no content

How do I go about getting 1 and 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with respect to namespaces:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse('in.html')
>>> names = {'cas':'http:///text/cas.ecore', 'xmi': 'http://blahblah'}
>>> doc.xpath('//cas:Sofa[@xmi:id="63"]', namespaces=names)
[<Element {http:///text/cas.ecore}Sofa at 0x10550a5f0>]
>>> doc.xpath('//cas:Sofa[@xmi:id="63"]/@String', namespaces=names)
['Find a contact']
>>> doc.xpath('//cas:Sofa[@xmi:id="72" and @ID="Third"]/@String', namespaces=names)
['Send a message']
```

Comment: Hi Guy, Could you give the first few lines of the program.  I get ttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'xpath'
How do I complete this:                                               `def main(argv):`
  elem_list=[]
  elem_num=0
  try:
    xmlfile=argv[0]
    doc=ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root=doc.getroot()
    for child in root:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python, but the following XPaths should do:

1.) `//*/@xmi:id`

2.) `//*[@xmi:id='72']/@String`

3.) `//*[@xmi:id='72' and @ID='Third']/@String`

Attributes are selected with `@`, conditions are created in brackets (`[]`).

Be aware that your XML uses namespaces. Instead of just selecting everything (`//*`), you should consider more specific XPaths (`/xmi:XMI/cas:Sofa`) and using a namespace manager.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me the complete command, just to know if I am missing anything.  I get an xmlXpathEval() failed error. :(  Coul dI use the xpath on each node?